# Can a different DNS server be used for subdomains?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian

I have a domain `example.com`, and subdomains `a.example.com` and `b.example.com` on a production server.

I also have a development server `dev.example.com`, with subdomains `a.dev.example.com` and `b.dev.example.com`.

Both of these servers are running their own DNS.

Is there a way to setup DNS so all `dev.example.com` and *.dev.example.com entries are located and configured on the `dev.example.com` DNS?

Basically, I want all of the subdomain lookups to go to my development server.  This way I don't have to log onto a separate server to manage DNS for my development box.

Comment: I don't think you can without programming. You want to resolve *.dev.example.com ---> *.example.com Alias can solve but is an static solution. I think you're looking for a dynamic solution right?

Comment: If not, how could "google.com" go on a different server from "serverfault.com"? Wouldn't they both have to be on the ones that handle "com"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The other answer made the assumption that:

> You want to resolve *.dev.example.com ---> *.example.com

But that's not how your question seems to read.  It sounds to me like you want to delegate control over the dev.example.com domain to your own machine.  If that's the case, then the delegation is easy:

- On whatever machine is your nameserver for example.com, you'd add an NS record that says your dev machine is the nameserver for dev.example.com
- You'd also add a glue record, an A record giving the IP of your dev machine.

In your case, if this is Bind, you'd have something like this on the nameserver for example.com:

```
$ORIGIN dev.example.com.
@             IN      NS     dev.example.com.
dev           IN      A      1.2.3.4
```

And then on your dev machine you'd set up Bind to be authoritative for dev.example.com  (You're on your own for this part, but it's straightforward.)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm not sure why my question got voted down so much.  Did I say something wrong?

Comment: @muncherelli The downvotes might be because it wasn't completely clear what you wanted to do.  I thought it sounded like you wanted to delegate nameserving to your dev machine and answered that.

Comment: I did not downvote the question, but I might have on the basis not only that it's unclear but on the basis that questions are supposed to demonstrate basic understanding of the subject matter, and both subdomain delegation and wildcard IPs are really very basic functions of DNS.

Comment: I didn't know I needed to prove my basic understanding of DNS to ask a question.  I've been making websites for over 15 years and I've never done this before.

Comment: That a great answer, but what happens if the IP changes? If the server of dev moves to `1.2.3.5`?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira If the IP changes, first you need to change the IP address at your domain's glue record. Then change the IP address in zone file in your `dev` machine.

Comment: What is the role of the "glue record" here? Is it not enough to set the nameserver for the subdomain and then set A/AAAA records in the subdomain's zone file on that nameserver?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, without a problem, this is one of the basic functions of DNS.

On the DNS server for example.com, you define the IP for dev.example.com, and that the NS for dev.example.com is dev.example.com, and on dev.example.com you define all the sub-names of dev.example.com.

Comment: This was a great answer too, gave the point to @Ward due to more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your use case, you might have some luck in setting up a local DNS with PowerDNS and it's recursor functionality https://www.powerdns.com/recursor.html

You can then use the forward-zones to delegate the resolution to various zones see the (not so great) documentation : https://doc.powerdns.com/md/recursor/settings/#forward-zones

I've heard good things about UnboundDNS https://unbound.net/ which should be able to provide solutions for this scenario too.